# Trying to do unneeded attach during debugging

Tags: c, debugging, dll, configuration-files

I have 2 projects in a VS2010 solution.  Project A generates an exe, Project B generates a DLL. The Project B DLL is used both by Project A in the solution, as well as a 3rd party program.  In release mode, Project A works normally.  But when I run Project A in debug mode, it tells me it is trying (and not succeeding) in attaching to the 3rd party program...which it has nothing to do with.
I've scoured the config files for Project A and can't see anywhere where this 3rd party program is referenced.  Any ideas?

Edit: the message is:

> "Unable to attach.  Process "...exe" is not running on Dell [my
>   computer].  Refresh the process list before attempting another
>   Attach."

Comment: Could you post the exact error message you're seeing?  What component is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your trying to debug project A, check if it is set as default project and check for the debug commandline or options.